# ExtJs 5 unable to set textfield width

Tags: extjs5

I am unable to set textfield width the same way i used to do in ExtJS 4. Setting different types of layouts (anchor, column) or even hardcoding width as textfield config have no effect. Textfield width remains the same. The panel is rendered in window.

```
    Ext.define('Dash.view.card.CardForm',{
        extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
        layout:{
            type:'hbox',
            align:'stretch'
        },
        frame:false,
        bodyPadding:25,
        initComponent:function() {


            this.items = [{
                xtype:'fieldset',
                title:'Form',
                layout:'anchor',
                flex:2,
                items:[{
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    fieldLabel:'Name',
                    name:'name',
                    anchor:'100%'
                },{
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    fieldLabel:'SET',
                    name:'set',
                    anchor:'100%'
                },{
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    fieldLabel:'Url',
                    name:'url',
                    anchor:'100%'

                },{
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    fieldLabel:'Price',
                    name:'price',
                    anchor:'100%'
                }]
            },{
                xtype:'fieldset',
                title:'Card Preview',
                flex:1,
                items:[{
                    xtype:'image',
                    name:'preview'
                }]
            }];

            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

Using chrome inspect i noticed that rendered div has proper width but it's child html input has no width.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from app startup with boostrap to standard script inclusion and forgot to include proper css file. After adding ext-theme-crisp-all.css file evertything is ok.